# How to connect local WebChat client to a bot running locally?

Tags: botframework, botconnector

Is it possible to talk to my bot via WebChat like I'm doing it via Emulator, Without registering and publishing the bot on Azure?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to register the bot in the BotFramework portal and enable the WebChat channel. Registering the bot doesn't mean that the bot will be published to the bot directory. You don't need to publish the bot to using it.

Also, you don't need to publish the bot in Azure to use it. Instead, you could use ngrok to create a secure tunnels to localhost.

You can check the following links:

- https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/guides/core-concepts/#debugging-locally-using-ngrok
- https://robinosborne.co.uk/2016/09/19/debugging-botframework-locally-using-ngrok/

### Update 21/12

Just remembered that since the WebChat is now [open source](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), you might have an option to run it locally as described in the [README.md](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/README.md). Below the relevant portion of the docs.

[image: How to run WebChat]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
So, it's not possible to run WebChat locally and talk via it to bot without registering the bot in the BotFramework portal (is that actually BotConnector?). I mean, when using the emulator, I'm neither enabling that channel in the BotFramework portal nor registering the bot.

In other words: In order to use WebChat:
1. I have to register the bot in the BotFramework portal
2. I may publish it to the bot directory, but it's not necessary 
3. I could use ngrok to create the endpoint on my local machine - or I could publish the bot on Azure, AWS or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, but I also just updated my answer with an alternative that might be better for your needs

Comment: Thanks. I saw that and I'm still confused why I have to register the bot when I want to use WebChat, but I don't have to when I use the emulator.

Comment: I forgot the mention in the previous comment that the readme in the 2nd step says - register the bot

Comment: If you want to run it locally, you still need to register the bot as you need a DirectLine secret. The WebChat is just a layer on top of the DirectLine API and thus, in order to use it you need to get a secret. The emulator might be abstracting all of that behind the scenes in the code (as it also based on the WebChat control). Any reason you are resisting to register the bot? There is nothing bad with that :)

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. Hahaha it may look like I'm resisting, I'm trying to understand why is the BotConnector necessary for WebChat and not for the Emulator; how is Emulator using DirectLine API without a secret, and if the communication between the Emulator and the locally hosted bot is going through BotConnector.

Anyway, I registered my bot and added the DirectLine channel, but I didn't get the secret - also I don't see the "generate direct line secret" button when configuring it.

I have to use ngrok in order to get "Messaging endpoint", right?

Comment: The emulator is open source as well so you might want to check it to know more: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator. You should enter to the DirectLine channel in the BotFramework portal and there you should see the Direct Line secret. Yes, you should use ngrok as well here I think.

Comment: Thanks for your tips Ezequiel.